Puppeteer PDF- Table Headers Overlapping When Deployed to Docker Container
For one reason or another, I can't get these PDFs to generate properly when I have this deployed. It appears to be an issue with Puppeteer because I can get it to print correctly even when I open the html in Chrome and print to pdf. See below for the docker file, puppeteer implementation, and HTML (It's a bit of a mess because of how the template is built, but you'll get the idea):
FROM node:20-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    chromium \
    nss \
    freetype \
    freetype-dev \
    harfbuzz \
    ca-certificates \
    ttf-freefont \
    fontconfig

RUN fc-cache -f -v

# Set environment variable to use Puppeteer with Chromium installed in non-standard location
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./
COPY .npmrc ./

# RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
RUN npm install pm2 -g
RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 4042

CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "/usr/src/app/process.yml" ]

import { launch } from 'puppeteer';

class FormatDocsApi {
    async formatHtmlString({ htmlString }) {
        const browser = await launch({
            headless: true,
            args: [
                '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins',
                '--disable-site-isolation-trials',
                '--autoplay-policy=user-gesture-required',
                '--disable-background-networking',
                '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
                '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows',
                '--disable-breakpad',
                '--disable-client-side-phishing-detection',
                '--disable-component-update',
                '--disable-default-apps',
                '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                '--disable-domain-reliability',
                '--disable-extensions',
                '--disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess',
                '--disable-hang-monitor',
                '--disable-ipc-flooding-protection',
                '--disable-notifications',
                '--disable-offer-store-unmasked-wallet-cards',
                '--disable-popup-blocking',
                '--disable-print-preview',
                '--disable-prompt-on-repost',
                '--disable-renderer-backgrounding',
                '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                '--disable-speech-api',
                '--disable-sync',
                '--hide-scrollbars',
                '--ignore-gpu-blacklist',
                '--metrics-recording-only',
                '--mute-audio',
                '--no-default-browser-check',
                '--no-first-run',
                '--no-pings',
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--no-zygote',
                '--password-store=basic',
                '--use-gl=swiftshader',
                '--use-mock-keychain',
            ],
        });
        console.log('Browser launched:', await browser.version());
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log('page created');
        await page.emulateMediaType('print');
        await page.evaluateHandle('document.fonts.ready');
        await page.setContent(htmlString, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
        const pdfOptions = {
            displayHeaderFooter: true,
            preferCSSPageSize: true,
            format: 'A4',
            headerTemplate: '<div></div>',
            footerTemplate:
                "<div style=\"font-size:8px; text-align:end; width:100%; margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;\"><span class='pageNumber'></span> / <span class='totalPages'></span></div>",
            margin: {
                top: '40px',
                bottom: '40px',
                left: '40px',
                right: '40px',
            },
        };
        console.log('PDF buffer generating now...');
        const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf(pdfOptions);
        // Close the browser
        await browser.close();
        return pdfBuffer; // Return a success message or data
    }
}

export { FormatDocsApi };

HTML/CSS

I'm running node 20, puppeteer v22, and browser is Chrome/123.0.6312.122.
I've been battling this for weeks and thought upgrading Node to 20 and Puppeteer to v22 would be the ticket, but it's still not working when deployed.

Does it work when you run your docker image locally?

@Kartoos I actually don't use a Docker container when running it locally. Super far from optimal, but to this point I've just been setting up my local environment to match that of the other devs on the team. My assumption is that it's either something tied to that or Puppeteer? I'm a little green when it comes to Docker at this point, so my troubleshooting in that department is definitely subpar.

I attempted to recreate the issue, but then it was printing undefined on the screen, so could not even run it locally. If possible can you also share how FormatDocsApi is being called? I copied the html as string and passed it. Possibly I am missing something

@Kartoos It's just passed in as a string by a Graqhql resolver, so for testing I've just been passing it in via a test.js file where I wrap the HTML (from the jsfiddle link) in a js variable and import it into the file with the FormatDocsApi.
Test file looks like this:
export const testHtmlString = `


.......`;
I have tried to reduce the given large html example to more manageable size, so that it can be replicated easily:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <style>
         #nss-summary-table-header {
         background-color: lightgrey;
         border-left: 0.1px solid black;
         border-right: 0.1px solid black;
         }
         .nss-summary-table-header {
         background-color: lightgrey;
         border-left: 0.1px solid black;
         border-right: 0.1px solid black;
         page-break-inside: avoid;
         }
         .nss-summary-table {
         border-collapse: collapse;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         table-layout: fixed;
         padding: 0 !important;
         float: none !important;
         }
         td {
         text-align: center;
         margin: 0 !important;
         height: 100%;
         padding-top: 2px;
         padding-bottom: 2px;
         } 
         th {
         text-align: center;
         margin: 0 !important;
         }
         tr {
         padding: 0 !important;
         margin: 0 !important;
         }
         .nss-summary-table-nested {
         border-collapse: collapse;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         table-layout: fixed;
         margin: 0 !important;
         padding: 0 !important;
         float: none !important;
         page-break-inside: avoid;
         }
         .nested-table {
         border-collapse: collapse;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         table-layout: fixed;
         margin: 0 !important;
         padding: 0 !important;
         float: none !important;
         page-break-inside: avoid;
         }
         .nss-summary-totals {
         width: 100%;
         display: table;
         border-collapse: collapse;
         }
         .nss-summary-totals td {
         padding-top: 4px;
         padding-bottom: 4px;
         }
         #nss-total-row div {
         text-align: left;
         background-color: white;
         margin: 2px;
         }
         #nss-total-row-wrapper {
         display: flex;
         justify-content: flex-end;
         width: 100%;
         margin-top: 10px;
         }
         #nss-disclaimer {
         font-style: italic;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
         page-break-after: always;
         }
         .nss-text-align-right {
         text-align: right !important;
         }
         .text-align-justify {
         text-align: justify;
         }
         .nss-border-left-none {
         border-left: none !important;
         }
         .nss-bold {
         font-weight: bold;
         }
         .nss-col-20-percent-w {
         width: 20%;
         } 
         .nss-col-25-percent-w {
         width: 25%;
         }
         .parent-td {
         width: 80%;
         }
         .border-left-none {
         border-left: none !important;
         }
      </style>
      <style>
         html {
         -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
         }
         body {
         font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
         font-size: .7rem;
         padding: 40px;
         height: 100%;
         page-break-inside: avoid;
         }
         hr {
         border-style: solid;
         border-bottom: 2px solid black;
         }
         hr.hr-bold {
         border-bottom: 4px solid black;
         }
         h1 {
         text-transform: uppercase;
         }
      </style>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div style="height: 800px">
      </div>
      <div id="name-search-summary">
         <br>
         <table class="nss-summary-table" style="border-top: 0.1px solid black;">
            <thead id="nss-summary-table-header" class="nss-summary-table-header">
               <tr>
                  <th class="nss-bold" colspan="5" style="background-color: #70A6AD; color: #ffffff; padding: 4px 1px; border-bottom: 0.1px solid black;">Client, Test </th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <th class="nss-bold">Jurisdiction</th>
                  <th class="nss-bold">Service</th>
                  <th class="nss-bold">Results</th>
                  <th class="nss-bold">Through Date</th>
                  <th class="nss-bold">Fees</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr style="">
                  <td colspan="5" style="padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;">
                     <table class="nss-summary-table-nested content-block is-first" style="border: 0.1px solid black;">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black;">
                              <td rowspan="2" class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">Recorder, Denver, CO</td>
                              <td colspan="4" class="parent-td" style="padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;">
                                 <table class="nested-table" style="">
                                    <tbody>
                                       <tr style="">
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black; padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">Federal Tax Lien Search</td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black; padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">
                                             None Found
                                          </td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black; padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">2/12/2024</td>
                                          <td rowspan="2" class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="padding: 4px 1px;">$80.00</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr style="">
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style=" padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">State Tax Lien Search</td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style=" padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">
                                             None Found
                                          </td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style=" padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">2/12/2024</td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                     <table class="nss-summary-table-nested content-block " style="border: 0.1px solid black;">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black;">
                              <td rowspan="2" class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">District Court, Big Stone, MN</td>
                              <td colspan="4" class="parent-td" style="padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;">
                                 <table class="nested-table" style="">
                                    <tbody>
                                       <tr style="">
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black; padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">Civil Search - Pending Only</td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black; padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">
                                             None Found
                                          </td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black; padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">2/12/2024</td>
                                          <td rowspan="2" class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="padding: 4px 1px;">$40.00</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr style="">
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style=" padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">Judgment Search</td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style=" padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">
                                             None Found
                                          </td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style=" padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">2/12/2024</td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                     <table class="nss-summary-table-nested content-block " style="border: 0.1px solid black;">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black;">
                              <td rowspan="2" class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">U.S. District Court, Minnesota District</td>
                              <td colspan="4" class="parent-td" style="padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;">
                                 <table class="nested-table" style="">
                                    <tbody>
                                       <tr style="">
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black; padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">Civil Search - Pending Only</td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black; padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">
                                             None Found
                                          </td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black; padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">2/12/2024</td>
                                          <td rowspan="2" class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="padding: 4px 1px;">$40.00</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr style="">
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style=" padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">Judgment Search</td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style=" padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">
                                             None Found
                                          </td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style=" padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">2/12/2024</td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                     <table class="nss-summary-table-nested content-block " style="border: 0.1px solid black;">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black;">
                              <td rowspan="1" class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">U.S. Bankruptcy Court, Minnesota Division</td>
                              <td colspan="4" class="parent-td" style="padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;">
                                 <table class="nested-table" style="">
                                    <tbody>
                                       <tr style="">
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style=" padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">Bankruptcy Search</td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style=" padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">
                                             None Found
                                          </td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style=" padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">2/12/2024</td>
                                          <td rowspan="1" class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="padding: 4px 1px;">$20.00</td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <table class="nss-summary-table" style="border-top: 0.1px solid black;">
            <thead id="nss-summary-table-header" class="nss-summary-table-header">
               <tr>
                  <th class="nss-bold" colspan="5" style="background-color: #70A6AD; color: #ffffff; padding: 4px 1px; border-bottom: 0.1px solid black;">Person, Christofer </th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <th class="nss-bold">Jurisdiction</th>
                  <th class="nss-bold">Service</th>
                  <th class="nss-bold">Results</th>
                  <th class="nss-bold">Through Date</th>
                  <th class="nss-bold">Fees</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr style="">
                  <td colspan="5" style="padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;">
                     <table class="nss-summary-table-nested content-block is-first" style="border: 0.1px solid black;">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black;">
                              <td rowspan="2" class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">Recorder, Denver, CO</td>
                              <td colspan="4" class="parent-td" style="padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;">
                                 <table class="nested-table" style="">
                                    <tbody>
                                       <tr style="">
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black; padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">Federal Tax Lien Search</td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black; padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">
                                             None Found
                                          </td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="border-bottom: 0.1px solid black; padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">2/12/2024</td>
                                          <td rowspan="2" class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style="padding: 4px 1px;">$80.00</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr style="">
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style=" padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">State Tax Lien Search</td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style=" padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">
                                             None Found
                                          </td>
                                          <td class="nss-col-20-percent-w" style=" padding: 4px 1px; border-right: 0.1px solid black;">2/12/2024</td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>

My observation is that the pdf print shows issues only inside docker. Thing to note is that inside docker, chromium's alpine linux version is installed. For me it was:
Chromium 123.0.6312.122 Alpine Linux

While on my MacOS it is:
Chrome/123.0.6312.122

I went inside running docker container using vscode (Dev Container extension) and was able to replicate the same behavior by running command line inside it without involving puppeteer:
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --print-to-pdf ./test.html

assuming the html is saved as test.html in the same directory. This generates output.pdf and we can test the behavior more easily.
Few More Observations:

The issue happens only when the first table goes to the next page and then the second table right after it merges with it
You can reduce the height in first div: <div style="height: 800px"></div>. If you reduce it enough to fit everything in single page (for example using height: 100px) the issue will not happen.

My guess is that this is a bug in chromium's alpine version rather than puppeteer/nodejs/docker. This is all I could find on the issue so far.

Thank you @Kartoos! This is a great place to work from!! I'll try to use a different version of Chromium and see what happens!

@BradyMPLS looks like it is not just an issue with chromium is alpine or not, or even chromium vs chrome. I am able to replicate the issue on my MacOS without even docker now! Just copy paste the html I have given into a test.html and open with your system chrome. Hit print pdf and keep all the default values and you will see the issue

If needed just change <div style="height: 800px"> height so that it gets splitted into two pages while printing pdf, this should make the issue appear on your system chrome browser itself
